# Parallels CTRl-Z Shortcut in Windows VM

Tags: window, parallels

I am using a `Windows 10 64 Bit` in `Parallels 13` on `iMac`.

Parallels maps the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd> keys to <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd> keys on the Windows VM.

All <kbd>CTRL</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd> mappings work, but <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> does not work.
Only <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> is working. <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> does nothing.

Does anyone have the same issue?
How can it be solved?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the solution.
The issue seems to be related with the German keyboard layout.
On German keyboards, the keys <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> are switched.
In Parallels, one has to add an additional mapping from <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>.
Then, kind of odd, <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> works as expected.